# Скролл модального окна

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, прокрутка

Имеется модальное окно (`bootstrap 3`):

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal1">            
    <div class="modal-dialog">                    
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Далее" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal2"/></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Из него по нажатию на кнопку "Далее" происходит закрытие окна #modal1 и вызов следущего модального окна #modal2

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal2">            
    <div class="modal-dialog">                    
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                TEXT //здесь много текста и форм
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Выход" data-dismiss="modal"/></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В первом окне работает скролл, а во втором нет, вероятно, происходит конфликт стилей, но не могу разобраться, как при открытии 2го окна сделать рабочим скролл.

JSFIDDLE: [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/386ozdb7/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавь в стили пару строк, заработает:

```
.modal {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal-open {
  overflow: auto;
}
```